# JavaScript append property to object

Tags: javascript, object, append

I am probably overlooking the most simple solution but I've tried anything I could come up with or find on the internet.

I'm trying to add a property to my JSON object which I need in my output. But whatever I try to add the property, it doesn't show up in my object. I verified that the 'doc' variable is an actual object.

No console errors. Console.log() shows the contents of 'doc' object and nothing more.

Anyone knows what is going on?

```
Blog.findOne({'slug': req.params.slug}, function(err, doc) {

  if (!err){

    if(_.isEmpty(doc)) { res.status(404).json({ response: "Nothing found here." }); } else {

      var blogPost = doc;
      blogPost.someProperty = 'test';
      console.log(blogPost); // doesn't contain new property

      res.status(200).json( { response: blogPost });

     }

   } else { throw err; }

 });
```

Output of blogPost/doc

```
{
  "response": {
    "_id": "55e31854823389ec1f5506fc",
    "title": "A sample post.",
    "slug": "a-sample-post2",
    "body": "Hello world. This is a sample post. \n\nThis should be a new paragraph.",
    "__v": 0,
    "date": "2015-08-30T14:51:00.836Z"
  }
}
```

A simple test like this in the browser does work. So I am really confused why it doesn't work in my NodeJS application. Something to do with callbacks/async or something?

```
var test = {}; 
test.prop = "test"; 
console.log(test);
Object {prop: "test"}
```

Comment: Any console errors? does it contain any properties at all?

Comment: @Amit no console errors and yes it contains what the original 'doc' contains, but nothing more.

Comment: I wonder if the objects's internal [[Extensible]] attribute is set to false

Comment: @MatthewVita - that was my next direction... :-). it probably IS. Jesse, wrap your `doc` with a new, simple object, and set the property(es) there: `var blogPost = {doc: doc, someProperty = 'test'};`

Comment: @MatthewVita Object.isExtensible(blogPost) = true (same for doc)
I'll post output of the doc, second!

Comment: @Juhana I'll give it a try! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `lean` function if you want to get result as `object`.

You could even reformat your code a bit to get rid of level of indentation.

```
Blog.findOne({'slug': req.params.slug}).lean().exec(function(err, doc) {

    if (err){
      throw err;
    }

    if(_.isEmpty(doc)) { 
       res.status(404).json({ response: "Nothing found here." }); 
       return;
    }

    // else is not required
    var blogPost = doc;
    blogPost.someProperty = 'test';

    res.status(200).json( { response: blogPost });
 });
```

Comment: thanks for the code optimalisation! should think more next time!

Comment: I always try to avoid nesting as much as possible. Makes it more readable ;)